# How to convert boolean and number type Json Key value to string type

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'am having a json object where it has different key values of string,boolean and number type.I want to convert the boolean and number type key value to string type..i.e.,eg:`{"rent":2000,"isPaid":false}` which is a valid json .Here i want to convert rent and isPaid to string type i.e.,`{"rent":"2000","isPaid":"false"}` which is also valid.for this I'am using replacer, but not working exactly how I require:

```
var json={"rent":2000,"isPaid":false};
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json, replacer);
function replacer(key, value) {
if (typeof value === "boolean"||typeof value === "number") {
return "value";
}
return value;
}
console.log(jsonString);
```

Then above code is consoling as: `{"rent":"value","isPaid":"value"}`

Then I replaced return `"value"` with return `'"'+value+'"'`  .Then on console it is giving `{"rent":"\"2000\"","isPaid":"\"false\""}`

So can someone help me so that it returns as `{"rent":"2000","isPaid":"false"}`

Any help is appreciable! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var json={"rent":2000,"isPaid":false};
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json, replacer);

function replacer(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === "boolean"||typeof value === "number") {
    return String(value);
  }
  return value;
}

console.log(jsonString);
```

We're using the `String()` function to convert your booleans and numbers to string. The output is:

```
{"rent":"2000","isPaid":"false"}
```

Comment: This is great as it checks the JSON at all the levels not just the root

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by this way...

```
var json={"rent":2000,"isPaid":false};
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json, replacer);
function replacer(key, value) {
if (typeof value === "boolean"||typeof value === "number") {
return value=""+value+"";
}
return value;
}
console.log(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `toString()` method to convert numbers/boolean to change them to string, as below:

```
var json={"rent":2000,"isPaid":false};
var temp = {};
json.forEach(function(val, key)
{
 temp[key] = val.toString();
});
json = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some reference, using [`JSON.parse(text[, reviver])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) "reviver" parameter.

```
    let reviver = (key, value) => 
    (typeof value === 'number' || typeof value === 'boolean') ? String(value) : value;
```